# What are all the spells that create one or more undead creatures?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, undead, necromancy

Since trying to Google this just keeps finding the specific spell called Create Undead...

What are all of the spells in D&D 5e that can be used to make an undead creature? I can think of Animate Dead, Create Undead, and Finger of Death, any others?

Comment: Does a spell count if it doesn't *create* an undead, but rather summons an existing one from somewhere else?

Comment: Do spells that can indirectly create undead count?

Comment: @SeriousBri what did you have in mind? We can add a second table for spells like that.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov Shapechange or True Polymorph into a shadow dragon

Answer (score 19, accepted):

At the time of writing, the below spells are the only ones which create one or more undead:

| Name | Level | Scales? | Spell List | Target/Notes | Source |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [*Animate Dead*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/animate-dead) | 3rd | Yes | Cleric, Wizard, Death Domain, Circle Of Spores, Oathbreaker | Targets bones or corpse | *Basic Rules*, pg. 212 |
| [*Create Undead*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/create-undead) | 6th | Yes | Cleric, Warlock[*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/warlock#MysticArcanum(6thlevel)-390), Wizard | Targets up to 3 corpses, can only cast at night | *Basic Rules*, pg. 229 |
| [*Danse Macabre*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/danse-macabre) | 5th | Yes | Warlock, Wizard | Targets up to five corpses; Concentration required | *Xanathar's Guide to Everything*, pg. 153 |
| [*Finger of Death*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/finger-of-death) | 7th | Yes | Sorcerer, Warlock[*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/warlock#MysticArcanum(7thlevel)-392), Wizard | CON Save; if a humanoid target dies, it becomes a zombie | *Basic Rules*, pg. 241 |
| [*Negative Energy Flood*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/negative-energy-flood) | 5th | No | Warlock, Wizard | CON Save; If it kills a non-undead, target rises as a zombie. | *Xanathar's Guide to Everything*, pg. 163 |
| [*Summon Undead*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/summon-undead) | 3rd | Yes | Warlock, Wizard | Concentration required; Stat block provided | *Tasha’s Cauldron of Everything*, pg. 114 |
| [*True Polymorph*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/true-polymorph) | 9th | No | Bard, Warlock[*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/warlock#MysticArcanum(9thlevel)-394), Wizard | Targets basically anything | *Basic Rules*, pg. 283 |

---

* Requires a Warlock to select this spell as a Mystic Arcanum

† Bards can acquire all these spells via the [Magical Secrets](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/bard#MagicalSecrets-592) class ability.